# .trim() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, trim

I have a very simple string that can contains a list which can possibly contain whitespace:

```
string = "one, two,three ";
```

I want to first split the string by `,` to create an array of three strings and then remove any whitespace using `.trim()`

```
array = string.split(',').trim();
```

which returns `"one","two","three"`

however sometimes it fails and returns an error `.trim() is not a function`

I read that `.trim()` returns a new string not a trimmed version of the current string. So i used a for loop to do the above:

```
array = string.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var item = array[i].trim();
    array.push(item);
}
```

which returns `"one","two","three"`

my question is, can anyone explain why i was getting the error only sometimes? if the array never changed from my example and can anyone provide a cleaner solution to my fix.

Comment: you should be getting `TypeError: array.split is not a function` every time, so it would never ever get the error you say you are getting

Comment: The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, from the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: There is no `split` method on an array. Even if you start with a string instead of an array then the `split` method returns an array and there is no `trim` method on an array. If you would push an item into the array that you are looping over, then you would never reach the end of the array, it would be an infinite loop. So, none of the code that you show would ever return anything at all.

Comment: if the first line is a typo and should be `array = "one, two,three ";` - then your last piece of code will run until the browser has had enough and begs you to stop the script running

Comment: sorry all, `string.split(',').trim();` returns an array so i just poorly named my example, the original var is a string as a lot of you suggest.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it was a typo as i was rewriting real code to make an easier to read example.. went well as you can tell. Fancy answering the updated as you seem knowledgeable on the subject.

Answer (score 6):

`split()` does not work on arrays, but on strings.
As you wrote your String into an array you have to get that string via `array[0]`, since the string is the very first Element.

If you splitted your string into an array you can call the map function and trim each value in your newly created array.
like this:

```
array = ["one, two,three "];
array = array[0].split(',')
array = array.map(function(a){return a.trim()})
```

Or in short:

```
array = ["one, two,three "][0].split(',').map(function(a){return a.trim()})
```

Answer (score 6):

In ES6 compliant runtime (i.e: node 4+) you can use use arrow function that gives you a less verbose code to achieve your goal:

```
> "one, two, three ".split(',').map(s => s.trim());
[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is apparent that there could be other problems with your codes but sticking specifically to your question **.trim() is not a function**, there is a change in how the function is called especially for jQuery 3.5 upwards. This is already explained elsewhere but brought here for quick reference:

For codes using jQuery 3.5 and below, the usual function call works:

```
let xString = " This is my string with spaces  ";
let xTrimmed = xString.trim();
```

But for codes using jQuery 3.5 upwards:

```
let xString = " This is my string with spaces  ";
let xTrimmed = $.trim(xString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this same issue trying to iterate the output of String.split using a "for (var i in splitTokens)". Note it only happened to me in the browser (Chrome in my case) i.e. not when using the same code in a node process.

It confused me until I hooked up a debugger and then I saw the problem. String.split returns an Array object instance (splitTokens), which has functions on it ("each" etc). The "for (var i in splitTokens)" loop iterates the functions too, so splitTokens[i] was getting back e.g. the each function of the Array instance, which caused things to explode if I tried to call e.g. "trim()" (because the function object doesn't have a function called trim()).